# How to run javascript on individual form fields in django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms

I am currently trying to get my registration template to run as I want it to. This includes having a check for a unique username, before the user submits the post. I plan on doing this by using javascript and Ajax, and by following this [tutorial](http://thepythondjango.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-django-project/).

If you look at the link, they've typed out each field in their form individually in their HTML file. I, am currently rendering my form using `{{ form.as_p ]}`.

I was wondering if there is a way to check what is in the username field so that that I can run the javascript/ajax while rending the form the I currently have it, or if I need to type out each field in the form manually.

Thanks

Comment: can you be a little clear of what are you trying to do

Comment: if you render the form as {{ form.as_p }} it will also have the fields, then write and ajax and a function in which you check if the username exists or not

Comment: You can access the appropriate form field as required by enclosing it in a div or a span: <div id="username">{{ form.name }}</div>

Comment: The clearway is to do this is ask the user to check for availability of the username they typed in the username input field. Provide a button to do this manually or trigger the ajax call when the user has finished entering it. Standard way (as of most email service providers) is to ask user to press a button to check availability of the username and if it is already taken give some suggestion to make it unique.